# How can i requeue a srun job of SLURM automatically if the jobs fails?

Tags: slurm

I have to run 300 jobs of the same model (black box). Yet sometimes a segmentation fault occurs inside the model with following error message:

```
srun: error: nodexyz: task 0: Segmentation fault
```

The cluster utilizes SLURM as resource manager and i want to requeue this job automatically if it fails.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding `|| scontrol requeue $SLURM_JOB_ID` at the end of the `srun` command so that if it fails and return a non-zero output code, the job will be requeued and re-scheduled. You can track the number of restarts with the `$SLURM_RESTART_COUNT`.